# How to clear an RTCEAGLVideoView after stopped rendering?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, webrtc

I am using multiple RTCEAGLVideoView to render different videos in my WebRTC application. When I switch user, the RTCEAGLVideoView retains the last rendered frame untill new frame is rendered. This causes a feeling of having two views with same image frame for few seconds. So I want to clear the RTCEAGLVideoView after stopping rendering in it. I have already tried clearing by:

```
[videoTrack removeRenderer:remoteVideoView]]; //remoteVideoView is an RTCEAGLVideoView 
videoTrack = nil;
remoteVideoView.hidden = true;
[remoteVideoView renderFrame:nil];
```

But this will not clear the RTCEAGLVideoView. As I understand, RTCEAGLVideoView is an RTCVideoRenderer which renders video frames in its bounds using OpenGLES 2.0 or OpenGLES 3.0. But the GLKView in it is not public and so we have only the view to work with. Does anybody know how to clear this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve this by re-initialising the RTCEAGLVideoView. There is no solution available to clear the frame rendered on it. What I did is

```
//Remove the RTCEAGLVideoView and assign nil 
if(_remoteVideoView != nil) {
        [_remoteVideoView removeFromSuperview];
        _remoteVideoView = nil;
  }

//Re-init the same RTCEAGLVideoView object
_remoteVideoView = [[RTCEAGLVideoView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

//Add back to the view
[self addSubview:_remoteVideoView];
```

Hope this helps someone.